# Changing Read-Only File to Write File

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android application in Java. I am creating a file, and when I tried to write some contents into the file, it is shown that the file is Read-Only in the debug logs. The path of the generated file is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG.jpg`.

I tried to make the file writable by using the `setWritable(true)` API function and  `Files.setAttribute(Paths.get(filePath), "dos:readonly", false)`, but no use. When I tried to use `setWritable(true)`, it results in `Permission to access file is denied` even though I added the corresponding permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Could anyone help me on how to solve this problem and make the read-only file writable?

Comment: If your app can create a file then it can write to it too. What you say makes no sense.